# Pandas Grouped Boxplot by Category to Compare 3 Datasets Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, group-by, boxplot

I am trying to produce a separate grouped boxplot figure by "site_name" for 3 datasets - 'obs','raw', and 'adj'. So, the final figure should have 3 grouped side-by-side boxplots of 'obs','raw', and 'adj' time series by 'site_name' or SITE A, SITE B in this example. I have data that looks like this:

```
    site_name   obs         raw         adj
0   SITE A  6.418529189 11.23949224 6.985811001
1   SITE A  8.788185389 14.97198142 9.321099071
2   SITE A  9.150093299 15.03959828 9.974189383
3   SITE A  8.960796086 14.53909986 10.08513361
4   SITE A  7.04010526  11.32339089 7.496043956
5   SITE A  7.750408473 12.23209169 7.893739255
6   SITE A  5.396922286 9.262985075 5.584104478
7   SITE A  4.842398234 8.77877907  5.436729651
8   SITE A  2.46593252  4.809821429 2.779181548
9   SITE A  5.650324669 9.868885673 6.720622287
10  SITE B  12.98071991 14.58748261 13.09878999
11  SITE B  8.768521796 9.628748068 8.751576507
12  SITE B  7.163978706 8.305841446 7.146397775
13  SITE B  7.765772425 8.367532468 7.540894661
14  SITE B  6.370840508 5.733239437 5.893661972
15  SITE B  4.46220486  5.286569343 4.356613139
16  SITE B  8.766229103 9.188587732 8.637717546
17  SITE B  7.648023594 7.622237762 7.481734266
18  SITE B  6.26515501  6.109928058 6.035798561
19  SITE B  6.962116967 8.466759388 7.241140473
```

And, I have tried this but it plots nothing and gives me an error -

```
df.boxplot(column=['site_name'],by=['obs','raw','adj'])
```

and this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

And, I have tried this code below but it plots 'obs', 'raw' and 'adj' columns in a separate group by site_name and that is not what I need. Here is this code that does not achieve the required result:

```
df.boxplot(column=['obs','raw','adj'],by=['site_name'])
```

[image]

thank you for your help,

Comment: Do you mean `df.groupby('site_name').boxplot(column=['obs','raw','adj'])`?

Comment: that's it!! thanks much!!

Comment: By using your solution, can i somehow scale the y axis for each plot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do groupby first then do boxplot on obs, raw, adj columns.

To customize the plot property, you can add `return_type='axes'` to get matplotlib axes, then you can call the customization function on the axes.

This pandas boxplot makes shared y-axis plot which means you cannot have different y limit in each plot.

I don't know how to disable the shared y-axis in this solution, however, I know how to achieve dynamic y-axis limits in alternative solution. (Please see Update below)

```
axes = df.groupby('site_name').boxplot(column=['obs','raw','adj'], return_type='axes')

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylim(0, 20)  # Change y-axis limit to 0 - 20
```

================================================

Update:

If you would like to apply different y limits to each plot, try with subplots in `matplotlib`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create 2 subplots for SITE A, SITE B in 1 row. By default, this will create 2 subplots that does not share the y-axis.
# To make shared y-axis, use plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# Create a boxplot per site_name and render in the subplots by passing ax=axs
df.groupby('site_name').boxplot(column=['obs', 'raw', 'adj'], ax=axs)

# Apply different y limits
axs[0].set_ylim(0, 50)  # For SITE A
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 20)  # For SITE B

# display my plots
fig
```

[image]

Comment: hi  - thanks again. sorry, what do you mean by "call the customization function on the axes?"

Comment: ah sorry, i just meant by call any available function on `axes` variable that is returned by the `boxplot` function.   In the above example, I call `set_ylim` function.  For more available functions for axes are documented here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html.

Comment: would you be able to summarize in steps your thinking so I am clear? The y axis is dynamic to each plot and needs to change for each plot somewhat so it seems like a looped solution might work better than the original with your set_ylim suggestion...?

Comment: I updated my answer, could you check if that is what you would like to achieve or I am missing anything.

Comment: thank you emma - this will work!